# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: google-app-engine, django-forms

I am using django form. When I submit form, I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'` Any idea? thanks

```
def post(self, id=None):
    user = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
    form = IForm(self.request.POST.items())

    if form.is_valid():
```

UPDATE 2

```
def post(self, id=None):
    user = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
    form = IForm(self.request.POST.items())
    if form.is_valid():
        #I(**form.cleaned_data).put()
        k = I()
        k.email = 'test@test.com'
        k.put()
        self.redirect(webapp2.uri_for('list'))
        return self.render_template('test_add.html', **template_values)
```

UPDATE 1

If I use `form = IForm(self.request.POST)`

then getting > `users
Enter a list of values.`

Form

```
class IForm(forms.Form):
 email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
 users = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, choices=get_my_choices())
```

I added `required=False`. then don't know why getting error

Comment: this is not the code causing the problem. please post your complete post handler.

Comment: @aschmid00 Ok code updated....

Comment: and the full traceback too please.

Comment: @aschmid00 Here is full traceback http://dpaste.org/wFf7s/. thanks for reply :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
  File "/home/sandhu/projects/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/forms/widgets.py", line 178, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name, None)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get
```

tells your that data is a list in this case and of course a list does not have any get() method. the issue is here:

```
form = IForm(self.request.POST.items())
```

try to log the results of self.request.POST.items()

edit:
use self.request.POST.items() returns a list of tuples. your forms.Form expects a dictionary. use self.request.POST instead

Comment: I just print the `self.request.POST.items()` and get `[('email', u'asdfsdf@gmail.com'), ('users', u'1')]
`

Comment: so thats the issue. it returns a list. i think you can use self.request.POST without calling items().

Comment: sry didnt see that. so now you should show the full traceback of the error happening with self.request.POST because that works fine for me.

Comment: i think that MultipleChoiceField expects a list of values but your form returns a single item. what is the result of self.request.POST.get('users')?

Comment: You are right. If I use `self.request.POST.get('users')` > result `8`. And If I use 'self.request.get_all('users')' > result `[u'1', u'8']`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8999/discussion-between-no-access-and-aschmid00)